# How to calculate array by given points labels?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with labels and values:

```
  { label: '09:00:00', value: 1 },
  { label: '09:10:00', value: 2 },
  { label: '10:02:00', value: 3 },
  { label: '10:30:00', value: 4 },
  { label: '11:02:00', value: 5 },
  { label: '11:02:20', value: 6 },
  { label: '11:45:00', value: 7 },
  { label: '12:00:00', value: 8 },
  { label: '13:00:00', value: 9 },
  { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 },
  { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 },
  { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 }
```

I want to convert this array to another array. the new array will have label and value properties.

But I do not need to display all the labels. only if the label is 09:00:00 or 11:00:00 or 13:00:00 or 15:00:00.

so in my array I have label 09:00:00 then it should be in the new array.

when I have `09:10:00` it greater than `09:00:00` so it should have empty string label.

so on until `11:02:00`, which have `11:00:00`, and belong to the group of `11:00:00`. and should have a label of `11:00:00`.

I try do it with `map` and `reduce` but one of them was the right answer.

```
const a = ['09', '11', '15'];

const b = [
  { label: '09:00:00', value: 1 },
  { label: '09:10:00', value: 2 },
  { label: '10:02:00', value: 3 },
  { label: '10:30:00', value: 4 },
  { label: '11:02:00', value: 5 },
  { label: '11:02:20', value: 6 },
  { label: '11:45:00', value: 7 },
  { label: '12:00:00', value: 8 },
  { label: '13:00:00', value: 9 },
  { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 },
  { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 },
  { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 }
]

const y = a.map(aa => {
  return b.filter(bb => bb.label.indexOf(aa) === 0);
});

console.log({ y });
```

Each item in the array, if the label is matched one of `09:00, 11:00, 13:00, 15:00`, then the value should belong to this point. otherwise the name should be empty.

for example the expected array should be:

```
{ label: '09:00:00', value: 1 },
{ label: '', value: 2 },
{ label: '', value: 3 },
{ label: '', value: 4 },
{ label: '11:00:00', value: 5 },
{ label: '', value: 6 },
{ label: '', value: 7 },
{ label: '', value: 8 },
{ label: '13:00:00', value: 9 },
{ label: '', value: 10 },
{ label: '15:00:00', value: 11 },
{ label: '', value: 12 },
```

I'm not sure how to calculate this array, do I need to do foreach inside foreach?

Comment: Can you please share some effort?

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to calculate"*, but what are you trying to calculate? Based in your input and desired output I didn't see any calculations, just a replace of strings, where label's first number matches another one, for empty string

Comment: I try to do it with reduce, map and forEach but its not was helpful.

Comment: @JonSud Then please share either attempt

Comment: In the new array the labels which not empty need to be one of the values `09:00, 11:00, 13:00, 15:00`. and still have the value of the original array

Comment: Please, be more clear in your question, we didn't understand what exaclty you want, why `10:00:00` is not listed in output? But anyway, share with us the attempted code. **[edit]** the question to avoid long comments

Comment: because I set the 09:00 and 11:00. the 10:00 is between. so it have no label...

Comment: Add those informations to the question itself, please, it is all relevant, and explain which calculation you are trying to do

Comment: why is this `{ label: '11:02:00', value: 5 }` morphing to `{ label: '11:00:00', value: 5 }`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array with the times that you don't want to blank out.
Then with a forEach you can blank out the labels that are not in that list.

Example snippet:

```js
let arr = [
 { label: '09:00:00', value: 1 },
 { label: '09:10:00', value: 2 },
 { label: '10:02:00', value: 3 },
 { label: '10:30:00', value: 4 },
 { label: '11:02:00', value: 5 },
 { label: '11:02:20', value: 6 },
 { label: '11:45:00', value: 7 },
 { label: '12:00:00', value: 8 },
 { label: '13:00:00', value: 9 },
 { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 },
 { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 },
 { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 }
];

let fixedhours = ['09', '11', '13', '15'];

let prevHour = '';
arr.forEach((x,idx)=> {
  let hour = x.label.substring(0,2);
  if(fixedhours.includes(hour) && hour !== prevHour) x.label = hour+':00:00';
  else x.label = '';
  prevHour = hour;
});
   
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: perfect! thanks!!!

Comment: what about I have label: `11:00:01`? or I don't have 11:00 in the list but 11:01?

Comment: @JonSud  Ok, I think the updated solution is more what you want.  Using a `prevHour` variable, so only the first occurence is changed, while others get blanked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach:

- Create a function to get the necessary slot where appointment should fall in.
- Create groups of appointments based on slot.
- Loop over each slot and remove label from all except first.
- Loop over group and merge all the groups together. This can be done as a part of previous step as well but I prefer keeping a step do only 1 thing.

**Sample:**

```js
function getTimeSlot(time) {
  const timeSlots = [ "09:00", "11:00", "13:00", "15:00" ];
  
  const [ hour, min ] = time.split(":");
  return timeSlots.reduce((slot, curSlot) => {
    const [ slotHour, slotMin ] = curSlot.split(':');
    return +slotHour <= +hour && +slotMin <= +min ? curSlot : slot;
  }, timeSlots[0]);
}

const data =   [ { label: '09:00:00', value: 1 }, { label: '09:10:00', value: 2 }, { label: '10:02:00', value: 3 }, { label: '10:30:00', value: 4 }, { label: '11:02:00', value: 5 }, { label: '11:02:20', value: 6 }, { label: '11:45:00', value: 7 }, { label: '12:00:00', value: 8 }, { label: '13:00:00', value: 9 }, { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 }, { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 }, { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 }];

const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, schedule) => {
  const key = getTimeSlot(schedule.label);
  acc[key] = (acc[key] || []).concat(schedule);
  return acc;
}, {});

let result = [];
for( let key in groupedData ) {
  result = result.concat( groupedData[key].map((item, index) => index ? { ...item, label: '' } : item ) )
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map new object and check if the wanted label is included in an `labels` array. If not take an empty string as value.

```js
function getLabel(label) {
    var labels = ['09', '11', '13', '15'],
        [h, m, s] = label.split(':');

    return 60 * m + +s <= 120 && labels.includes(h)
        ? h + ':00:00'
        : ''
}

var data = [{ label: '09:00:00', value: 1 }, { label: '09:10:00', value: 2 }, { label: '10:02:00', value: 3 }, { label: '10:30:00', value: 4 }, { label: '11:02:00', value: 5 }, { label: '11:02:20', value: 6 }, { label: '11:45:00', value: 7 }, { label: '12:00:00', value: 8 }, { label: '13:00:00', value: 9 }, { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 }, { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 }, { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 }],

    result = data.map(o => ({ ...o, label: getLabel(o.label)}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` and `momentjs` to get the result

```js
const matches = ['09:00', '11:00', '13:00', '15:00'];

const input = [
{ label: '09:00:00', value: 1 },
  { label: '09:10:00', value: 2 },
  { label: '10:02:00', value: 3 },
  { label: '10:30:00', value: 4 },
  { label: '11:02:00', value: 5 },
  { label: '11:02:20', value: 6 },
  { label: '11:45:00', value: 7 },
  { label: '12:00:00', value: 8 },
  { label: '13:00:00', value: 9 },
  { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 },
  { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 },
  { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 }
];

const output = input.map(item => {
  const isMatching = matches.some(match => moment(item.label, "HH:mm:ss").hours() === moment(match, "HH:mm:ss").hours());
  return { label: isMatching ? item.label : '', value: item.value };
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is missing 11:00:00, isn't it?

Comment: yes it missing that.

Comment: @JonSud, it isn't in the data. why should it in?

Comment: @JonSud Updated the answer. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

I have done this one...

```js
const myRaay = 
    [ { label: '09:00:00', value:  1 }, { label: '09:10:00', value:  2 }, { label: '10:02:00', value:  3 }
    , { label: '10:30:00', value:  4 }, { label: '11:02:00', value:  5 }, { label: '11:02:20', value:  6 }
    , { label: '11:45:00', value:  7 }, { label: '12:00:00', value:  8 }, { label: '13:00:00', value:  9 } 
    , { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 }, { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 }, { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 } 
    ] 

const regex = /^09:|11:|13:|15:/;
let ref = '';

for( let mim of myRaay)
  {
  let key = (mim.label).match(regex)

  if ( !Boolean(key) || key[0] == ref )
    { mim.label = '' }
  else  
    {
    mim.label = key + '00:00'
    ref = key[0]
  } }


myRaay.forEach(mim=>console.log(JSON.stringify(mim)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

the same inside a reduce ;)

```js
const myRaay = 
    [ { label: '09:00:00', value:  1 }, { label: '09:10:00', value:  2 }, { label: '10:02:00', value:  3 }
    , { label: '10:30:00', value:  4 }, { label: '11:02:00', value:  5 }, { label: '11:02:20', value:  6 }
    , { label: '11:45:00', value:  7 }, { label: '12:00:00', value:  8 }, { label: '13:00:00', value:  9 } 
    , { label: '14:00:00', value: 10 }, { label: '15:00:00', value: 11 }, { label: '16:00:00', value: 12 } 
    ] 

const regex = /^09:|11:|13:|15:/;

let temp = myRaay.reduce((a,c,i,t)=>{
  let k = (c.label).match(regex)
  if ( !Boolean(k)
     || k[0]===a) { t[i].label=''        }
  else    { a=k[0]; t[i].label=a+'00:00' }
  return a
},'' )

// proof
myRaay.forEach(mim=>console.log(JSON.stringify(mim)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide to the `forEach` a function that will be executed on all the array elements, something like this:

```
yourArray.forEach((element) => element.label = yourMatchingFunction(element.label) ? element.label : "");
```